# How do I encrypt/decrypt a dictionary in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, encryption

I have a dictionary, `myDict = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}`, that I'd like to encrypt and write to an external raw text file.
I've already downloaded and installed PyCrypto since a lot of other threads seem to recommend it, but it's too confusing for me to grasp its terminology and syntax.
Could someone explain how I'd go about doing this in Layman's terms?

Comment: I realize this is a similar post to my last, but this one is asking how to **encrypt**, not encode.

Comment: I don't see the difference. Encrypt is a kind of encoding. If your problem is with the concept of encoding/decoding something to a file than this question is a duplicate. If your question is about how to use PyCrypto, then it has nothing to do with `dict`s, since the other question already tells you how to convert from-to strings and `dict`s, and you should have asked how to use PyCrypto in general(which I believe would be a duplicate of an some other question).

Comment: Encoding uses a scheme that is publicly available.  
Encryption uses a unique format that only the coder should know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Encode the dict as a string with e.g. `json`, and then encrypt the resultant string.